# Concurrency and CacheLoader.load()

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, guava

Should I synchronize the code in CacheLoader.load()?

I have code like this:

```
final Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

final LoadingCache<Key, Value> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<Key, Value>(){
        @Override
        public Value load(final Key key) throws Exception {
            return calculator.calc(key);
        }} );
```

If the cache needs to load the values of two different keys from two different threads do I have to worry about thread interference in my Calculator object? I.e. should I declare my Calculator.calc() method synchronized (or do something else to ensure thread-safety)?

**Edit**

Just so that it is clear I am asking specifically with regards to caching in Guava: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: if you do not modify data inside the method there is no need to synchronize it

Comment: Make sure the values you get from the cache are immutable. You will painfully suffer if you want to share mutable state with the cache construct. If you have to modify, create a new instance of the object instead by `invalidat`ing the value for the given key. Getting the value is thread safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The depends on the thread-safety of the action in the `load` method. It IS possible for it to be executed concurrently for different keys. Therefore if the action is not thread-safe, it should be made so in some way (synchronizing being the most trivial option).

So, if `calculator.calc(key)` is not thread-safe, synchronize it. If it is, don't.

Comment: Just to be sure. Are you answering this wrt to guava caching or just by looking at the code I wrote?

Comment: Guava. It applies to caching in general but this answer is Guava-specific in that Guava does blocking for the same key which some other caches do not.

Answer (score 0):

If threads are going only to read, then you don't have to synchronize. If the threads are going to manipulate the value of the cache, then both read and write operations should be synchronized.

Comment: This is too trivial an answer. What if the code called `SimpleDateFormat.format`? Is that a read or a write? I am not manipulating data. But it turns out that this method is not thread-safe, therefore I would need to synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who answered.

I have checked this with a little test program and there IS thread interference. Specifically for different keys when the CacheLoader has to be invoked, these calls are not synchronized so if Calcualtor.calc() is not thread-safe, then weird results will ensue.